# Check if a nohup script is running or start it

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

we are running a tool on different machine by calling the shell script to run it,
the script is in background by using "nohup scriptname ", for some reasons which i don't know the script stops after some time, i want to make a script to keep on checking if the script is stopped and runs it again.

I have very little knowledge on shell script, but suddenly this requirement came and i searched on google but not getting proper answer, please help.

Comment: Could you be more precise and give a snippet. How do you connect and run the script on remote machines?

Comment: no worries,take it as simple like the script is running on my linux system,i just want to check if its still running or start it again if not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple and working solution.

First, the script which has to be run again, let's call it `bar.sh`:

```
#! /bin/bash

echo "bar is living"
sleep 5
echo "bar is dying"
exit
```

Second, the script which runs `bar.sh` and watches for his death, called `foo.sh`:

```
#! /bin/bash

while true ; do

    echo "Running bar ..."
    ./bar.sh &

    echo "Waiting bar's termination"
    wait
done
```

Now just type in the terminal:

```
$ chmod +x foo.sh bar.sh
$ ./foo.sh
```

Comment: very very thanks and +1 for this example, can i run it using the nohup too

Comment: will this also work if bar.sh was terminated abnormaly

Comment: Yes; it will survive to the end of your terminal, and the output will be saved in a file, or mailed to you by the system.

Comment: thanks i understand programming basics like while(forever) run the script and wait for it exit, it was really a great help. Thanks

Comment: one last question, if you are still there if i am calling java program in last line of my script, will the script run till the program ends, or it terminates just after calling.

Comment: and how do I terminate this infinitely running script in background

Comment: It will wait if you run it in foreground.

Comment: to kill the script, save it's PID somewhere (for instance in a file) so that you can do `kill PID` when needed.

Comment: "foreground only" i think this was the main cause of when i was running with nohup the script would end, is there any way so that the script would wait when it is in background (nohup) too. ?